# ARR (Application Request Routing) reverse proxy not working on DNN web site

Tags: dotnetnuke, reverse-proxy, dotnetnuke-7, arr

On DNN 7.0 I need to setup a reverse proxy using the ARR module (Application Request Routing).

The rewriting rules are working on static resources (PNG,JS,etc) but not on HTML content.

The error from the advanced trace is 
GENERAL_NOT_SEND_CUSTOM_ERROR SETSTATUS_TRYSKIP

Answer (score 2):

The problem caused by the internal url rewrite module used by DNN, look at your web.config>

This module conflicts with the ARR management, the solution is to create a separate web application inside the DNN web site and to apply the rewriting rules on this new path.

Here are the steps:

1. Create a new web app inside the DNN web site
2. Configure the web.config accordingly (remove RequestFilter and handlers coming from the DNN web.config).
3. Change the rewriting rules in order to catch the new path.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for saving me a lot of time

Comment: I used this feature when I needed to call a web service on another domain inside my web application using javascript, overriding the cross domain limitation of the browser. What is your scenario ?